# Microsoft Access 2010 (mdb) automation with user based security

Tags: ms-access

Macros and VB macros are very limited in Access.

I've good C#/.NET skills and created an app with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObject` (captures some process) to use with `Microsoft.Office.Interop` (makes some Office stuff).

It's works like a charm with .accdb files (MS ACCESS 2010), but when i want to automate mdb base with security...

For example, i can't get Access process with opened DB:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE \server\database.mdb /WRKGRP "\server\security.mdw"*

New process just starts.

I decided to create an Office Add-In for Access 2010... but when user opens shortcut above - it's just not loading.

Is there any possible solution to open/get/capture Access process with opened mdb database?

**upd1:** i'll try to play with msaccess cmd startup arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it!**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114/

Look at GetShellApp method - you can pass any arguments and connect to encrypted\user-based-access DB